# MVC Dropdown Not Working a 2nd Time on Main Page only

Tags: html, model-view-controller, razor, bootstrap-4

Having a small, weird, issue in which my drop down menu works properly once on the main page of my MVC application. If I close the drop down and try to open it again it wont work, however if I go to a different page from the drop down, I can open and close it as much as I want and it will work just fine, the issue only occurs on the main Home page of the application.

Below is my _layout.cshtml code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Page Name Here</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body> 
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: crimson">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">               
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="color: antiquewhite">
                        Menu
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" @Html.ActionLink("About Us", "About", "Home")</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" @Html.ActionLink("Visit Us", "Visit", "Home")</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()       
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    <script src="~/Scripts/umd/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code for the main Home page:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="4000">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="~/Images/img1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="1">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="~/Images/img2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="2">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="~/Images/img3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="3">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="~/Images/img4.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="3">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<hr />

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Getting started</h2>
        <p>
            ASP.NET MVC gives you a powerful, patterns-based way to build dynamic websites that
            enables a clean separation of concerns and gives you full control over markup
            for enjoyable, agile development.
        </p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301865">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Get more libraries</h2>
        <p>NuGet is a free Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to add, remove, and update libraries and tools in Visual Studio projects.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301866">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Web Hosting</h2>
        <p>You can easily find a web hosting company that offers the right mix of features and price for your applications.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301867">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

My About Us and Visit Us page have the default info from Visual Studio when you first create your MVC project with prebuild views.

If additional info is needed please do let me know. Thanks in advance.